# Change variable through function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, variable-assignment

I am trying to automate the changing of a variable through a function. However although it returns the right value, it doesn't change the actual value of the variable passed to it.

```
function change(one, two){
   one = two;
   return one;
}

var test = 1;

change(test, 5);
// returns 5;

console.log(test);
// still 1
```

Why does this happen and how can I solve this?

Comment: Any more detail? I'm a beginner.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bzt2dkta(v=vs.94).aspx - reading should give you a better idea of how it works.

Comment: Generally you'd do `test = change(test, 5)` instead of trying to change the variable values inside the function. If you described *why* you want to do it this way, perhaps you'd get a solution to your *real* problem.

Comment: Thanks @Juhana. I could use the `test=change(test,5)` syntax. It's just slightly longer and I have to use the function a lot so would've been more convenient to do it more compactly.

Answer (score 1):

You can't pass variables. When you call `change(test, 5);` you are passing the *value* of `test` not the *variable* `test`.

That value is copied to the variable `one`.

You then assign a new value to `one`, but that doesn't touch `test`.

---

If you want to do anything like this, you need to pass an *object* and then modify the value of a property of the object.

```js
function change(one, two){
   one.test = two;
   return one.test;
}

var myObject = {
  test: 1
  };

change(myObject, 5);
console.log(myObject.test);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this in JavaScript. Variables cannot be passed by reference, they are always passed by value.